# jqGrid filling select in EditForm

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I use jqGrid  4.2.0. In EditForm there are two selects:
1) REGION_ID - it fills in form opening
2) TOWN_ID   - must show towns of the selected region

When I open the form in first time and change REGION the list of towns is not changeing and the function **regionOnChange** is not called.
But when I close the form and click "Add" button again after changing region the list of towns changes.

Please help to solve this problem.

```
colModel: [
                  { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 30, align: 'left', hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true} },
                  { name: 'NAME', index: 'NAME', width: 250, align: 'left', editable: true, editoptions: { size: 64} },
                { name: 'REGION_ID', index: 'REGION_ID', hidden: true, edittype: "select", editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }
                    , editoptions: { dataUrl: '/Directory/GetRegion?countryId_=0',
                        buildSelect: function(data) {
                            var d = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
                            var s = '<select id="TOWN_ID">';
                            if (d.length) {
                                $.each(d, function(i) {                                        
                                        s += '<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.name + '</option>';
                                });
                            }
                            return s + "</select>";
                        }
                        }
                    },                    
                { name: 'TOWN_ID', index: 'TOWN_ID', hidden: true, edittype: "select", editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }
                    , editoptions: { dataUrl: '/Directory/GetTowns?regionId_=62',
                        buildSelect: function(data) {
                            var d = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
                            var s = '<select>';
                            if (d.length) {
                                $.each(d, function(i) {                                        
                                        s += '<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.name + '</option>';
                                });
                            }
                            return s + "</select>";
                        }
                    }
                },
```

...

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
            { del: false, add: true, edit: false, search: false, jqModal: true },  //options
            {},                                                     //edit option
            {width: 450, jqModal: true, closeAfterAdd: true, afterSubmit: processAddEdit, afterShowForm: processShowForm
                ,onInitializeForm: onInitFrm },                     //add option
            {},                                                     //del
            {},                                                     //search
            {}                                                                                                            
            );
```

And this is the code how TOWN list is changing after selecting enother REGION

```
    function onInitFrm(formid) {    
       $("select").filter("#REGION_ID").change(regionOnChange);
    }
    function processShowForm(formid) {           
        $("select").filter("#REGION_ID").change(regionOnChange);
    }

    function regionOnChange(reg) {
        var f = $("select[id='REGION_ID'] option:selected").val();
        $("select[id='TOWN_ID'] option").remove();
        if (f > 0) {
            $.getJSON("/Directory/GetTowns", { regionId_: f }, getTown);
        }
    }

    function getTown(tow) {
        $("select[id='TOWN_ID'] option").remove();
        $("select[id='TOWN_ID']").append("<option value=0> </option>");

        $.each(tow, function(i) {         
            $("select[id='TOWN_ID']").append("<option value=" + this.id + ">" + this.name + "</option>");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by adding this line : `, dataEvents: [{ type: 'change', fn: regionOnChange}]`
to editoptions. ))